# How to know if a number is odd or even in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, parity

I have an array of numbers typed `Int`.

I want to loop through this array and determine if each number is odd or even.

How can I determine if a number is odd or even in Swift?

Answer (score 142, accepted):

```
var myArray = [23, 54, 51, 98, 54, 23, 32];
for myInt: Int in myArray{
  if myInt % 2 == 0 {
    println("\(myInt) is even number")
  } else {
    println("\(myInt) is odd number")
  }
}
```

Comment: Oh Sorry! yes it's dead straight. Actually, while coding i had an compile error in the above code. Due to which it was showing me errors on the line (Where i was using % and / operators) as well.

Comment: Here's a functional approach:
let numbers = [0, 1, 2, 3]
let evenNumbers = numbers.filter { $0 % 2 == 0 }
let oddNumbers = numbers.filter { $0 % 2 != 0 }

Comment: I'm using this with .isHidden, such as `img1.isHidden = pageNumber % 2 == 0` and `img2.isHidden = pageNumber % 2 != 0`

Answer (score 36):

Use the `%` [Remainder Operator](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/BasicOperators.html) (aka the Modulo Operator) to check if a number is even:

```
if yourNumber % 2 == 0 {
  // Even Number
} else {
  // Odd Number
}
```

or, use [`remainder(dividingBy:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/double/2884269-remainder) to make the same check:

```
if yourNumber.remainder(dividingBy: 2) == 0 {                
  // Even Number 
} else {
  // Odd Number
}
```

Comment: Well there is better and much faster way to do it using AND (&) operator

let inputArray = [23,25,2,4,9]
for x in inputArray {
if ( x&1 == 1) {
    print ("odd")
} else {
    print ("even")
}
}

Comment: @i.AsifNoor I agree with You. But modulus (getting rest from division) operation has same code in all languages.

Comment: SHORT WAY 
extension Int {
    func isEven() -> Bool {
        return (self % 2 == 0)
    }
}

Comment: **Still shorter**: `extension Int { var isEven: Bool { return (self % 2 == 0) } } `

Comment: :D stupidity.   You mean to create `isEven` method as extension of `Int` type. But overall You've to check if it's odd or even. So You'll use `if ... else...` with `isEven` method. So where is shortening? In fact if You'll just once why do abstraction on primitives? What's gain?

Comment: @ReinhardMänner seems like people forgot about such methods like: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/double/2884269-remainder

Comment: @num8er: If you have to do such checks often, then it is indeed shorter to write `anyInt.isEven` as `(anyInt % 2 == 0)`. In any way, it is clearer. And the link that you provided applies to `Double`, not to `Int`. Do you really think that applying `remainderReportingOverflow(dividingBy other: Int) -> (partialValue: Int, overflow: Bool)` to an `Int` is better than what I suggested?

Comment: @ReinhardMänner I'm not saying what is better or not. I'm saying mostly it's being happened once in an app. So we are talking about same things but with different words.

Answer (score 29):

Swift 5 adds the function `isMultiple(of:)` to the `BinaryInteger` protocol.

```
let even = binaryInteger.isMultiple(of: 2) 
let odd = !binaryInteger.isMultiple(of: 2)
```

This function can be used in place of `%` for odd/even checks.

---

This function was added via the Swift Evolution process:

- [Preliminary Discussion in Swift Forum](https://forums.swift.org/t/even-and-odd-integers/11774)
- [Swift Evolution Proposal](https://github.com/robmaceachern/swift-evolution/blob/binaryinteger-iseven-isodd/proposals/nnnn-binaryinteger-iseven-isodd-ismultiple.md)
- [Accepted Swift Evolution Implementation](https://forums.swift.org/t/accepted-with-modifications-se-0225-adding-ismultiple-to-binaryinteger/15689)

Notably, `isEven` and `isOdd` were proposed but *not* accepted in the same review:

> Given the addition of `isMultiple(of:)`, the Core Team feels that `isEven` and `isOdd` offer no substantial advantages over `isMultiple(of: 2)`.
>
> Therefore, the proposal is **accepted with modifications**. `isMultiple(of:)` is accepted but `isEven` and `isOdd` are rejected.

If desired, those methods can be added easily through extension:

```
extension BinaryInteger {
    var isEven: Bool { isMultiple(of: 2) }
    var isOdd:  Bool { !isEven }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

"Parity" is the name for the mathematical concept of Odd and Even:

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_(mathematics)

You can extend the Swift `BinaryInteger` protocol to include a `parity` enumeration value:

```
enum Parity {
    case even, odd

    init<T>(_ integer: T) where T : BinaryInteger {
        self = integer.isMultiple(of: 2) ? .even : .odd
    }
}

extension BinaryInteger {
    var parity: Parity { Parity(self) }
}
```

which enables you to `switch` on an integer and elegantly handle the two cases:

```
switch 42.parity {
case .even:
    print("Even Number")
case .odd:
    print("Odd Number")
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `filter` method:

```swift
let numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
let odd = numbers.filter { $0 % 2 == 1 }
let even = numbers.filter { $0 % 2 == 0 }
```