# How can I know if a number is even or odd using the while operator?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, xcode, integer

How can I get to the same result but using the while operator instead? Also, printing which ones are even and which ones are odd

```
var arrayNumber: Array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

for myInt: Int in arrayNumber {
    if(myInt % 2 == 0) {
        print("\(arrayNumber) is even number")
    } else {
        print("\(myInt) is odd number")
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify your question?  `while` what?  Do you want to stop at the first odd number?  Print odd/even for all numbers (in which case a `for` is more appropriate)

Comment: Using the while operator, to do the same functionality as a "for in loop" would but using while instead and to return the output for which numbers are even and which are odd

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to know if a number is odd or even in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24056985/how-to-know-if-a-number-is-odd-or-even-in-swift)

Comment: Hey @pkamb, thanks for trying to help, someone has answered but for some reason deleted his code, but unfortunately it does not answer my question because the while operator hasn't been used, it needs to do the same functionality as in the link above but using the operator while instead, and to print which ones are odd and which ones are even

Answer (score 1):

The best thing to do is use an iterator for the while loop. `it.next()` will return `nil` if there are no more elements in the array.

```
let arrayNumber = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
var it = arrayNumber.makeIterator()
while let next = it.next() {
    if next % 2 == 0 {
        print("even", next)
    } else {
        print("odd", next)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Rob, that's a great way to tackle it, but I need it to return the odd numbers as well instead of a nil value

Comment: @YanesSkrabe What do you mean you need to return odd numbers? You never mentioned returning. All you are doing above is printing. Do you mean you need to print odd numbers?

Comment: Yes, that's right, to print the odd numbers, someone has answered but I suppose that the author deleted the following :     
var arrayNumber = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
var index = 0
while index < arrayNumber.count {
   var num = arrayNumber[index]
   if (num % 2 == 0) {
       print("\(num) is an even number")
   } else {
       print("\(num) is an odd number")
   }
   index += 1
}

Comment: I bet you could have pieced that together yourself ;) Anyways, answer updated.

Comment: I appreciate your help!

Comment: @YanesSkrabe better to use `BinaryInteger` `isMultiple(of:)` method.

Comment: @LeoDabus Thanks, I didn't know that method existed. But how is it better than using the modulo operator.

Comment: Better readability. It might also be more efficient but I haven't checked its implementation yet.  You can read about the [evolution proposal](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0225-binaryinteger-iseven-isodd-ismultiple.md)

Comment: There is some conditions check before returning the modulo operation

Comment: `@inlinable public func isMultiple(of other: Self) -> Bool {` `// Nothing but zero is a multiple of zero.` `if other == 0 { return self == 0 }` `// Special case to avoid overflow on .min / -1 for signed types.` `if Self.isSigned && other == -1 { return true }` `// Having handled those special cases, this is safe.` `return self % other == 0`
`}`